# Bootstrap datepicker setStartDate not working properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using Bootstrap datepicker and on selecting different values from a list its startdate is changing. It is working fine if I set the startdate 2013 from 2008 but it doesn't work if a select start date 2008 and currently its 2013.

What could be the reason here?

```js
$('#datepicker').datepicker('setStartDate', updatedDate);
```

This line I am executing whenever I select different startDate.

Comment: You should post your code, otherwise there's little anyone can do.

Comment: @lukas84 sorry I will do it now

Answer (score 0):

Really need to know what updatedDate value is.

However, if you read the docs for the dtepicker the value passed in must be a string that is understandable by format

https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#setstartdate
https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#startdate

> Date or String. Default: Beginning of time
>
> The earliest date that may be selected; all earlier dates will be
>   disabled.
>
> Date should be in local timezone. String must be parsable with format.

So what you pass in as the format option must match the format of your start date. If you do not set the format optin, the default is "mm/dd/yyyy"

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing code, I can only hypothesize; try calling [...]`.datepicker('update', 'date_string');` on the object to force an update on the control.